# Difficulty in getting the matrix of red, green,blue

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
 a = imread('Sample1.jpg');
 imshow(a)
```

This gives me the image but my problem is stated as below

It happens that I have an image in RGB format then how to get 3 different matrix of red
    ,green,blue respectively in Mat lab , I have also searched the documentation but can't
     get satisfactory reply  , I also want to store this values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If your image is truecolor then `A` will be an `m x n x 3` array. You get your channels by indexing the third dimension, R for example would be `A(:, :, 1)`

Comment: @excaza - Apologies.  I did not see your comment.  Shall I delete my answer?

Comment: @rayryeng nope, all good

Answer (score 4):

Using [`imread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) produces a 3 slice matrix, so accessing red, green and blue individually is simply:

```
R = a(:,:,1);
G = a(:,:,2);
B = a(:,:,3);
```

You use the third dimension of `a` to get the colour channel you want.  They are ordered as red, green and blue respectively (hence RGB).

Comment: This same data I want to store in a .text file in a proper order Can I do this??

Comment: Yup.  Just use `dlmwrite` on the matrix.

Comment: More Over if I am writing this code in a new editor window than I am not getting output can you please help me with that

Comment: @Saul_goodman - What "output" are you not getting? You seem to mistake me for a mind reader.

Comment: When I writ the above code in default command window I am getting perfect values , but when I am writting the same code in a next file to save it I am not getting any error , but the output is also not coming inthe command window

Comment: @Saul_goodman - What "output" do you want?  Do you want the file to **return** the matrices?  If it's a script file, just remove the semi-colons.  You'll see the output.